# Auto click listener in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

we are trying to set auto clickListener to perform auto calculation after taking input from user. Just like calculator while user put the input and calculation perform automatically. If i perform calculation in tvProcessor (2+3+2) then after clicking on equal button result show in tvResult is (7). Is this possible to run click listener automatically while i perform any calculation.

If we press(2+3) then without clicking on btnEqual, get result automatically as 5

```
String processor;
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   
    tvProcessor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_process);
    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
  
    btnTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_two);
    btnThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_three);
    btnPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
    
    btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
            tvProcessor.setText(processor + "2");
        }
    });
    btnThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
            tvProcessor.setText(processor + "3");
        }
    });

       
    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
            tvProcessor.setText(processor + "+");
        }
    });
 
    btnEqual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            processor = tvProcessor.getText().toString();
            Context rhino = Context.enter();
            rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
            String result = "";

            try{
                Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();
                result = rhino.evaluateString(scope, processor, "JavaScript", 1, null).toString();
            }catch (Exception e){
                result = "Error";
            }

            tvResult.setText(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can use `addTextChangedListener` to listen for text changes in an `EditText`

Comment: Please add a little more context and/or code snippets to clear up your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); 

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // write your logic
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```